# Should I apply my Schengen visa at the French or Swiss Embassy?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I have a question regarding my Schengen visa application for a personal trip. I am very confused and the Swiss Embassy employee I met today in my visa appointment claimed that I cannot apply for the visa from Switzerland and have to go to the French Embassy and rejected my application. So I wanted to confirm where I should apply.

I am travelling to Zurich, Switzerland for 2 days in June - specifically on June 15 to 16. Then, I plan to travel to Paris, France for 3 days in July, arriving on the night of July 12 and leaving early morning on July 15. Because I am travelling to Switzerland first, I thought I should apply there. However, the person at the Swiss Embassy said that I should apply at the French Embassy as my trip to France is 1 day longer and hence that is my main country. Is this true, though I am travelling there a month later?

Comment: This looks like two trips. not one. Unless you are going somewhere else for four weeks?

Comment: Yes, I concur with @MichaelHampton. Clarify where you will be between 17th of June and 11th of July and when **outside** of Schengen area and a multiple entry visa is being applied: go back to the Swiss Embassy with that information.

Comment: yes I will be outside the Schengen area in the intermediate time. I will be back in UK from June 17 to July 11. And then I will go to Paris.